# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index" while performing full vacuum on the database

Tags: postgresql-9.2, reindex, vacuum

While performing vacuum full, I have  received the below highlighted error. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

```
 ​/opt/postgres/9.2/bin/psql -p 5433 --username=cmuser  cpcm -c "VACUUM
FULL ANALYZE;"
```

ERROR:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index" DETAIL:  Key (starelid, staattnum,
>   stainherit)=(18915, 6, f) already exists.

' pg_statistic ' is a meta data table. Is it ok if I remove one duplicated record from ' pg_statistic' table?.